# make a method which returns the number of one digit numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I’m trying to make a method which will find the amount of one digit numbers in an array and return the value for example if my array is [1,22,3,4,55,66,5] it will return 4 because there is 4 one digit numbers and is in java

Comment: There are two main ways of doing this.  Probably the simpler one for a new developer is to write a `for` loop that iterates through the array and increments a counter when it finds a number within the appropriate range.

Comment: Hint: One digit numbers are greater than or equal to zero **and** less than or equal to nine.

Comment: Thank you I will try that it would also be appreciated if someone could write some code it would help out a lot

Comment: To add to @ElliottFrisch comment, whenever number >=0 && number <=9 is true, increment the counter. Finally return that counter.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch What about negative numbers? :p

Comment: So would I write an if statement with the for loop so it constantly  checks if it’s greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 9

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment. You need to give it a try and then ask question with some sample code.

Answer (score 2):

because I'm bored...

```
public static int getOneDigitNumberCount(final int[] numbers)
{
    if (numbers == null || numbers.length == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int count = 0;

    for (int number : numbers)
    {
        //  assumes you're not considering negative numbers
        if (number >= 0 && number <= 9)
        {
            count++;
        } 
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: @JonathanSwift No problem, but remember in the future that this community expects an individual to show some code/effort.

Comment: This answer is technically perfect, but I feel oddly compelled to downvote.  I'm not sure who benefits when a student receives a complete solution to their homework for free.

Answer (score 1):

And another solution that uses `streams` and also considers `negative` one digit numbers.

```
       int[] nums = {1,22,3,4,-8, -9, -45, 55,66,5};
       long count = Arrays.stream(nums)
               .filter(n -> n > -10 && n < 10)
               .count();
       System.out.println(count); // prints 6
```

Comment: +1 I love me some streams!  The only reason I didn't provide this solution is that it is overly complicated for the individual asking the question.

Comment: I agree they can be challenging.  Especially if one is weak on `generics`.  But they have been around since Java 8 and we're already up to Java 13.  Perhaps some examples will whet their appetite.

Comment: I hope so!  Unfortunately, it seems like students are more focused on the grade than the understanding. :(